# knowing a device special file major and minor numbers in linux

Tags: linux, file, device

All files in `/dev` are special files... they represent devices of the computer.
They were created with the `mknod` syscall. My question is: How can I know the minor and
major numbers that were used to create this special file?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The list is called the **LANANA Linux Device List**, and it is administered by Alan Cox.

You can find the [latest copy](http://www.lanana.org/docs/device-list/) online ([direct link](http://www.lanana.org/docs/device-list/devices-2.6+.txt)), or in the Linux source.  Its filename in the kernel tree is [`Documentation/devices.txt`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.31/Documentation/devices.txt).

To see the major and minor numbers that created a node in `/dev` (or any device node for that matter), simply use `ls` with the `-l` option:

```
22:26 jsmith@undertow% ls -l /dev/xvd?
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    202,   0 Nov  1 20:31 /dev/xvda
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    202,  16 Nov  1 20:31 /dev/xvdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk    202,  32 Nov  1 20:31 /dev/xvdc
```

In this example, `202` is the three devices' major number, and `0`, `16`, and `32` are minors.  The `b` at left indicates that the node is a block device.  The alternative is `c`, a character device:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root tty       5,   0 Nov 22 00:29 /dev/tty
```

Comment: hey thanks! but I was asking how to do this by commandline... :D

Comment: Do what by command line? Your question doesn't say anything about the command line, except `mknod`.

Comment: Looks like the lanana.org domain has expired ("lanana.org expired on 04/10/2012 and is pending renewal or deletion").  I hope that gets fixed - looks like it might be a bit of a recurring problem: https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/Minutes_Apr_27_2011

Answer (score 10):

```
$ ls -l /dev/fd0 /dev/null
brw-rw---- 1 root floppy 2, 0 Nov 22 19:48 /dev/fd0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root   1, 3 Nov 22 19:48 /dev/null
$ stat -c '%n: %F, major %t minor %T' /dev/fd0 /dev/null
/dev/fd0: block special file, major 2 minor 0
/dev/null: character special file, major 1 minor 3
```

Most device numbers are fixed (i.e. `/dev/null` will always be character device `1:3`) but on Linux, some are dynamically allocated.

```
$ cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
...
 10 misc
...

Block devices:
...
253 mdp
254 device-mapper
$ cat /proc/misc
...
 57 device-mapper
...
```

For example, on this system, it just so happens that `/dev/mapper/control` will be `c:10:57` while the rest of `/dev/mapper/*` will be `b:254:*`, and this could differ from one boot cycle to another -- or even as modules are loaded/unloaded and devices are added/removed.

You can explore these device registrations further in `/sys`.

```
$ readlink /sys/dev/block/2:0
../../devices/platform/floppy.0/block/fd0
$ cat /sys/devices/platform/floppy.0/block/fd0/dev
2:0
$ readlink /sys/dev/char/1:3
../../devices/virtual/mem/null
$ cat /sys/devices/virtual/mem/null/dev
1:3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use stat.

```
$ stat -c 'major: %t minor: %T' <file>
```

Answer (score 2):

Especially for block devices:

```
$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   90G  0 disk
├─sda1    8:1    0    4G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0    4G  0 part /
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative that doesn't depend on `stat`:

```
$ cat /sys/class/*/random/dev
1:8
```